# exam question that i could not do

Tags: natural-numbers

How many natural numbers less than 1000 are divisible by 5 or 7 but NOT by 35?
(a) 285 (b) 313 (c)341 (d) 243

i know that numbers upto 1000 that are divisible by 5 are 1000/5=200 and by 7 are 142. so total numbers that are divisible by 5 or 7 =342. then i am blank about how to progress. i guess we have to find area of divisibles of 5 and 7 excluding the area common between them in venn diagram representation.

Comment: Try using $\#(A\cup B) = \# A+\#B -\#(A\cap B)$.

Comment: You're well on your way! You then have to figure out how many are divisible by 35 and then, indeed, a Venn diagram should help.

Comment: The answer is $$\bigg\lfloor\frac{1000}5\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor\frac{1000}7\bigg\rfloor-2\bigg\lfloor\frac{1000}{35}\bigg\rfloor$$I've leave it to you to figure out why.

Comment: i get it 28 numbers are divisible by 35 upto 1000. then we get  union set of a and b =342-28=314. then what to do. oh i get it now. we get union set then we have to subtract the set of 35 from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly, the number of numbers divisible by $35$ from $1$ to $999$ is $\left[\frac{999}{35}\right]=28$, so the answer is $199+142-2\times28=285$. Also, you are to use $999$ and not $1000$ (owing to the "less than $1000$" in your question) for getting your sort of Venn diagram areas.
So, to put it exactly, it is

$$\left[\frac{999}{5}\right]+\left[\frac{999}{7}\right]-2\times\left[\frac{999}{35}\right]=285$$
**Explanation to the Venn-diagram approach:**

(i) There are $28$ numbers that are divisible by both $5$ and $35$(numbers divisible by $35$ are also divisible by $5$)

(ii) There are $28$ numbers that are divisible by both $7$ and $35$(numbers divisible by $35$ are also divisible by $7$)

These $28$ numbers each of which are being counted twice (once the first term and once in the second term) are to be removed from the enumeration.

Comment: answer in my exam key is 285.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited it.